# Finding an upper bound for Binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Consider choosing $s$ leaders from a team with size $n$ where $k$ of team members are corrupted and others are honest.

I am wondering to know how can I find an upper bound for the probability less than t members of leaders are honest?

Assumption: trials are independent with probability $p=\frac{n-k}{n}$ of success.

Comment: Two things are unclear here. a) What does "(uniform distribution)" refer to? Is $n$ uniformly distributed? If so, over which interval? b) What do you mean by the last paragraph? That the leaders are chosen independently with replacement, so a person could be picked as a leader more than once? But then there would be fewer than $s$ leaders. On the other hand, if the choice is without replacement (as one would expect when $s$ leaders are chosen), then the choices are not independent. Either way, there seems to be a contradiction between the first and last paragraphs. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.  I'm sorry, "(uniform distribution)" was a mistake.  In the case of the last paragraph, a person could be picked as a leader more than once but we count it once because $s$ distinct leaders are needed.

Comment: OK, so we make $m\ge s$ trials, each time selecting each of the $n$ team members with equal probability $\frac1n$, so we have the same probability $\frac{n-k}n$ every time of picking an honest member, and we do this until $s$ distinct leaders have been selected? The net effect of this is the same as if we'd just uniformly randomly select one of the $\binom ns$ combinations of $s$ members as leaders.

Comment: For simplicity, we can assume that $s \lll n$. Yes, all team members have been distributed uniformly. So each trial is a Bernoulli experiment with probability $p=\frac{n-k}{n} $ of success and repeating it gives a Binomial distribution. Computing the probability of less than t honest leaders is straightforward using Binomial formula. However, how can I found an upper bound for that?

Comment: No, that's not a Bernoulli distribution, since you're discarding the successes in the cases where you've already selected the person previously.

Comment: We assume that $s\lll n$, in fact, we can ignore it.

Comment: I see. But then the whole setup is just a big distraction, no? What you really want to do is to bound $\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}\binom sjp^j(1-p)^{s-j}$ from above?

Comment: It's a distraction but it really doesn't matter. Bounding $\sum_{j=0}^{t-1} p^{j}(1-p)^{s-j}$ from above is what I want to do

Comment: Without the binomial coefficients?

Comment: I forget to add binomial coefficients. Bounding $\sum_{j=0}^{t-1} \binom{s}{j} p^{j}(1-p)^{s-j}$ from above is what I want to do